# How to spin up a docker container (or docker-compose) with cloud-init (cloud-config)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cloud-init

I try to spin up a server which should run docker and docker-compose with a simple "hello-world" container. My YAML file looks like this:

```
#cloud-config
ssh_authorized_keys:
  - ssh-rsa MY_SSH_KEY_HERE

package_update: true
package_upgrade: true

packages:
  - docker.io

runcmd:
  - [ sh, -c, "sudo apt install -y docker" ]
  - [ sh, -c, "sudo apt install -y docker-compose"]
  - [ sh, -c, "sudo service docker start" ]

rancher:
  services:
    rancher-server:
      image: hello-world
      restart: always
      ports:
      - 80:80
      environment:
        - TEST_VAR=TEST
```

**Docker gets installed but wont start the image**

```
root@test ~ # which docker
/usr/bin/docker
root@test ~ # which docker-compose
/usr/bin/docker-compose

> sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

BTW: is it necessary to include the `packages: docker.io` ?

Answer (score 2):

In this answer, you can ignore adding default azure user to docker group if you are not using Azure VM. But keep in my mind to run docker you have to add your current user to docker group otherwise you may get permission denied error.

```
#cloud-config

package_update: true

# Setup swap memory
disk_setup:
    ephemeral0:
        table_type: mbr
        layout: [66, [33, 82]]
        overwrite: True
fs_setup:
    - device: ephemeral0.1
      filesystem: ext4
    - device: ephemeral0.2
      filesystem: swap
mounts:
    - ["ephemeral0.1", "/mnt"]
    - ["ephemeral0.2", "none", "swap", "sw", "0", "0"]

# Enable Docker's swap limit support (System restart required)
bootcmd:
    - [ sh, -c, 'sudo echo GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=\"cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1\" >> /etc/default/grub' ]
    - [ sh, -c, 'sudo update-grub' ]

# Install latest stable docker and docker-compose
runcmd:
    - [ sh, -c, 'curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh' ]
    - [ sh, -c, 'sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/docker/compose/releases/latest | grep "tag_name" | cut -d \" -f4)/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose' ]
    - [ sh, -c, 'sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose' ]
    - [ sh, -c, 'sudo docker run -d nginx:latest' ]

# Add default azure user to docker group
system_info:
    default_user:
        groups: [docker]

# Restart the system
 power_state:
   delay: "now"
   mode: reboot
   message: First reboot
   condition: True
```

Answer (score 1):

This user-data string is working for me on DigitalOcean using `ubuntu-18-04-x64` VM type.  I expect it would work on any version of Ubuntu 18.04 built for a cloud virtual machine.

```
#cloud-config

# https://github.com/number5/cloud-init/blob/master/doc/examples/cloud-config-apt.txt
# https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/
apt:
  sources:
    download-docker-com.list:
      source: "deb https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $RELEASE stable"
      key: |
        -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

        mQINBFit2ioBEADhWpZ8/wvZ6hUTiXOwQHXMAlaFHcPH9hAtr4F1y2+OYdbtMuth
        lqqwp028AqyY+PRfVMtSYMbjuQuu5byyKR01BbqYhuS3jtqQmljZ/bJvXqnmiVXh
        38UuLa+z077PxyxQhu5BbqntTPQMfiyqEiU+BKbq2WmANUKQf+1AmZY/IruOXbnq
        L4C1+gJ8vfmXQt99npCaxEjaNRVYfOS8QcixNzHUYnb6emjlANyEVlZzeqo7XKl7
        UrwV5inawTSzWNvtjEjj4nJL8NsLwscpLPQUhTQ+7BbQXAwAmeHCUTQIvvWXqw0N
        cmhh4HgeQscQHYgOJjjDVfoY5MucvglbIgCqfzAHW9jxmRL4qbMZj+b1XoePEtht
        ku4bIQN1X5P07fNWzlgaRL5Z4POXDDZTlIQ/El58j9kp4bnWRCJW0lya+f8ocodo
        vZZ+Doi+fy4D5ZGrL4XEcIQP/Lv5uFyf+kQtl/94VFYVJOleAv8W92KdgDkhTcTD
        G7c0tIkVEKNUq48b3aQ64NOZQW7fVjfoKwEZdOqPE72Pa45jrZzvUFxSpdiNk2tZ
        XYukHjlxxEgBdC/J3cMMNRE1F4NCA3ApfV1Y7/hTeOnmDuDYwr9/obA8t016Yljj
        q5rdkywPf4JF8mXUW5eCN1vAFHxeg9ZWemhBtQmGxXnw9M+z6hWwc6ahmwARAQAB
        tCtEb2NrZXIgUmVsZWFzZSAoQ0UgZGViKSA8ZG9ja2VyQGRvY2tlci5jb20+iQI3
        BBMBCgAhBQJYrefAAhsvBQsJCAcDBRUKCQgLBRYCAwEAAh4BAheAAAoJEI2BgDwO
        v82IsskP/iQZo68flDQmNvn8X5XTd6RRaUH33kXYXquT6NkHJciS7E2gTJmqvMqd
        tI4mNYHCSEYxI5qrcYV5YqX9P6+Ko+vozo4nseUQLPH/ATQ4qL0Zok+1jkag3Lgk
        jonyUf9bwtWxFp05HC3GMHPhhcUSexCxQLQvnFWXD2sWLKivHp2fT8QbRGeZ+d3m
        6fqcd5Fu7pxsqm0EUDK5NL+nPIgYhN+auTrhgzhK1CShfGccM/wfRlei9Utz6p9P
        XRKIlWnXtT4qNGZNTN0tR+NLG/6Bqd8OYBaFAUcue/w1VW6JQ2VGYZHnZu9S8LMc
        FYBa5Ig9PxwGQOgq6RDKDbV+PqTQT5EFMeR1mrjckk4DQJjbxeMZbiNMG5kGECA8
        g383P3elhn03WGbEEa4MNc3Z4+7c236QI3xWJfNPdUbXRaAwhy/6rTSFbzwKB0Jm
        ebwzQfwjQY6f55MiI/RqDCyuPj3r3jyVRkK86pQKBAJwFHyqj9KaKXMZjfVnowLh
        9svIGfNbGHpucATqREvUHuQbNnqkCx8VVhtYkhDb9fEP2xBu5VvHbR+3nfVhMut5
        G34Ct5RS7Jt6LIfFdtcn8CaSas/l1HbiGeRgc70X/9aYx/V/CEJv0lIe8gP6uDoW
        FPIZ7d6vH+Vro6xuWEGiuMaiznap2KhZmpkgfupyFmplh0s6knymuQINBFit2ioB
        EADneL9S9m4vhU3blaRjVUUyJ7b/qTjcSylvCH5XUE6R2k+ckEZjfAMZPLpO+/tF
        M2JIJMD4SifKuS3xck9KtZGCufGmcwiLQRzeHF7vJUKrLD5RTkNi23ydvWZgPjtx
        Q+DTT1Zcn7BrQFY6FgnRoUVIxwtdw1bMY/89rsFgS5wwuMESd3Q2RYgb7EOFOpnu
        w6da7WakWf4IhnF5nsNYGDVaIHzpiqCl+uTbf1epCjrOlIzkZ3Z3Yk5CM/TiFzPk
        z2lLz89cpD8U+NtCsfagWWfjd2U3jDapgH+7nQnCEWpROtzaKHG6lA3pXdix5zG8
        eRc6/0IbUSWvfjKxLLPfNeCS2pCL3IeEI5nothEEYdQH6szpLog79xB9dVnJyKJb
        VfxXnseoYqVrRz2VVbUI5Blwm6B40E3eGVfUQWiux54DspyVMMk41Mx7QJ3iynIa
        1N4ZAqVMAEruyXTRTxc9XW0tYhDMA/1GYvz0EmFpm8LzTHA6sFVtPm/ZlNCX6P1X
        zJwrv7DSQKD6GGlBQUX+OeEJ8tTkkf8QTJSPUdh8P8YxDFS5EOGAvhhpMBYD42kQ
        pqXjEC+XcycTvGI7impgv9PDY1RCC1zkBjKPa120rNhv/hkVk/YhuGoajoHyy4h7
        ZQopdcMtpN2dgmhEegny9JCSwxfQmQ0zK0g7m6SHiKMwjwARAQABiQQ+BBgBCAAJ
        BQJYrdoqAhsCAikJEI2BgDwOv82IwV0gBBkBCAAGBQJYrdoqAAoJEH6gqcPyc/zY
        1WAP/2wJ+R0gE6qsce3rjaIz58PJmc8goKrir5hnElWhPgbq7cYIsW5qiFyLhkdp
        YcMmhD9mRiPpQn6Ya2w3e3B8zfIVKipbMBnke/ytZ9M7qHmDCcjoiSmwEXN3wKYI
        mD9VHONsl/CG1rU9Isw1jtB5g1YxuBA7M/m36XN6x2u+NtNMDB9P56yc4gfsZVES
        KA9v+yY2/l45L8d/WUkUi0YXomn6hyBGI7JrBLq0CX37GEYP6O9rrKipfz73XfO7
        JIGzOKZlljb/D9RX/g7nRbCn+3EtH7xnk+TK/50euEKw8SMUg147sJTcpQmv6UzZ
        cM4JgL0HbHVCojV4C/plELwMddALOFeYQzTif6sMRPf+3DSj8frbInjChC3yOLy0
        6br92KFom17EIj2CAcoeq7UPhi2oouYBwPxh5ytdehJkoo+sN7RIWua6P2WSmon5
        U888cSylXC0+ADFdgLX9K2zrDVYUG1vo8CX0vzxFBaHwN6Px26fhIT1/hYUHQR1z
        VfNDcyQmXqkOnZvvoMfz/Q0s9BhFJ/zU6AgQbIZE/hm1spsfgvtsD1frZfygXJ9f
        irP+MSAI80xHSf91qSRZOj4Pl3ZJNbq4yYxv0b1pkMqeGdjdCYhLU+LZ4wbQmpCk
        SVe2prlLureigXtmZfkqevRz7FrIZiu9ky8wnCAPwC7/zmS18rgP/17bOtL4/iIz
        QhxAAoAMWVrGyJivSkjhSGx1uCojsWfsTAm11P7jsruIL61ZzMUVE2aM3Pmj5G+W
        9AcZ58Em+1WsVnAXdUR//bMmhyr8wL/G1YO1V3JEJTRdxsSxdYa4deGBBY/Adpsw
        24jxhOJR+lsJpqIUeb999+R8euDhRHG9eFO7DRu6weatUJ6suupoDTRWtr/4yGqe
        dKxV3qQhNLSnaAzqW/1nA3iUB4k7kCaKZxhdhDbClf9P37qaRW467BLCVO/coL3y
        Vm50dwdrNtKpMBh3ZpbB1uJvgi9mXtyBOMJ3v8RZeDzFiG8HdCtg9RvIt/AIFoHR
        H3S+U79NT6i0KPzLImDfs8T7RlpyuMc4Ufs8ggyg9v3Ae6cN3eQyxcK3w0cbBwsh
        /nQNfsA6uu+9H7NhbehBMhYnpNZyrHzCmzyXkauwRAqoCbGCNykTRwsur9gS41TQ
        M8ssD1jFheOJf3hODnkKU+HKjvMROl1DK7zdmLdNzA1cvtZH/nCC9KPj1z8QC47S
        xx+dTZSx4ONAhwbS/LN3PoKtn8LPjY9NP9uDWI+TWYquS2U+KHDrBDlsgozDbs/O
        jCxcpDzNmXpWQHEtHU7649OXHP7UeNST1mCUCH5qdank0V1iejF6/CfTFU4MfcrG
        YT90qFF93M3v01BbxP+EIY2/9tiIPbrd
        =0YYh
        -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

# Search for package versions: $ apt-cache madison docker-ce
packages:
- docker-ce=5:19.03.5~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
- docker-compose=1.17.1-2
- containerd.io=1.2.10-3

users:
- name: user
  uid: 1000

# Test Docker installation with $ docker run -u 1000 -t -i --rm hello-world
```